Do processes share the read-only sections of common dynamically loaded libraries?
I would like to verify how the memory consumption works when I have two different executables that depend on the same dynamically loaded library and the library has both "state" (i.e., something that should be specific per process) and const data (i.e., something that could be shared).
I designed the following very simple experiment:
main.cpp:
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include "mylib.h"

int main()
{
    MyLib lib;

    while (true)
    {
        lib.printString();
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
    }

    return 0;
}


lib.h:
#ifndef MYLIB_H
#define MYLIB_H

class MyLib
{
public:
    void printString();

private:
    int counter = 0;
};

#endif // MYLIB_H

lib.cpp:
#include "mylib.h"
#include <iostream>

// Define the large string in the implementation file
constexpr const char *largeString =
    "This is a very large string that will be used to fill up the .text section "
    "of the shared library. It needs to be big enough to be noticeable........................................................ ";

void MyLib::printString()
{
    std::cout << largeString << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Counter: " << ++counter << std::endl;
}

I compiled the sources using the following commands:
g++ -fPIC -shared -o libmylib.dylib my lib.cpp -std=c++11

g++ -o main main.cpp -L. -lmylib -pthread

Finally, I executed main twice.
First, I used vmmap on both processes to see that there are actually non-writable regions related to my dylib (Which may be the same). I got the following (for the first process):
__TEXT                      102ec4000-102ec8000    [   16K    16K     0K     0K] r-x/rwx SM=COW          ***/libmylib.dylib
__DATA_CONST                102ec8000-102ecc000    [   16K    16K     0K     0K] r--/rw- SM=COW          ***/libmylib.dylib
__LINKEDIT                  102ecc000-102ed0000    [   16K    16K     0K     0K] r--/rwx SM=COW          ***/libmylib.dylib

The regions were different, but as far as I understood, these indicate virtual memory, thus, they still be mapping to the same physical memory.
I continue by using dtruss to check how the dylib is loaded and I saw the following related sections:
8740/0x15967:      1207      12     11 open("libmylib.dylib\0", 0x0, 0x0)    = 3 0

 8740/0x15967:      1208       1      0 fcntl(0x3, 0x32, 0x16BCDDFB8)        = 0 0

 8740/0x15967:      1208       0      0 close(0x3)       = 0 0

 8740/0x15967:      1213       2      1 stat64("libmylib.dylib\0", 0x16BCDDB10, 0x0)         = 0 0
 8740/0x15967:      1215       1      1 stat64("libmylib.dylib\0", 0x16BCDD540, 0x0)         = 0 0

 8740/0x15967:      1221       6      5 open("libmylib.dylib\0", 0x0, 0x0)   = 3 0

 8740/0x15967:      1224       3      2 mmap(0x0, 0x9AB0, 0x1, 0x40002, 0x3, 0x0)        = 0x104574000 0

 8740/0x15967:      1224       1      0 fcntl(0x3, 0x32, 0x16BCDD658)        = 0 0

 8740/0x15967:      1225       0      0 close(0x3)       = 0 0

 8740/0x15967:      1235       6      5 open("/Users/***/memoryFootprint/libmylib.dylib\0", 0x0, 0x0)        = 3 0

 8740/0x15967:      1235       1      0 fcntl(0x3, 0x61, 0x16BCDD308)        = 0 0

 8740/0x15967:      1243       8      7 fcntl(0x3, 0x62, 0x16BCDD308)        = 0 0

 8740/0x15967:      1254      10      9 mmap(0x104580000, 0x4000, 0x5, 0x40012, 0x3, 0x0)        = 0x104580000 0

 8740/0x15967:      1257       2      1 mmap(0x104584000, 0x4000, 0x3, 0x40012, 0x3, 0x4000)         = 0x104584000 0

 8740/0x15967:      1258       1      0 mmap(0x104588000, 0x4000, 0x1, 0x40012, 0x3, 0x8000)         = 0x104588000 0

 8740/0x15967:      1259       0      0 close(0x3)       = 0 0

and a bit further: 

8740/0x15967:      1802       6      5 open("/Users/***/memoryFootprint/libmylib.dylib\0", 0x0, 0x0)         = 3 0

 8740/0x15967:      1803       1      0 __mac_syscall(0x19373BFDD, 0x2, 0x16BCDCE10)         = 0 0

 8740/0x15967:      1808       5      3 map_with_linking_np(0x16BCDCC90, 0x1, 0x16BCDCCC0)       = 0 0

 8740/0x15967:      1808       0      0 close(0x3)       = 0 0

 8740/0x15967:      1809       1      0 mprotect(0x104584000, 0x4000, 0x1)   = 0 0

 8740/0x15967:      1830       1      0 shared_region_check_np(0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF, 0x0, 0x0)         = 0 0

 8740/0x15967:      1832       1      0 mprotect(0x104530000, 0x40000, 0x1)  = 0 0

 8740/0x15967:      1845       2      1 access("/AppleInternal/XBS/.isChrooted\0", 0x0, 0x0)         = -1 Err#2

 8740/0x15967:      1862       3      1 bsdthread_register(0x193A3DD2C, 0x193A3DD20, 0x4000)         = 1073746399 0

 8740/0x15967:      1884       1      0 getpid(0x0, 0x0, 0x0)        = 8740 0

 8740/0x15967:      1888       3      2 shm_open(0x1938D8F51, 0x0, 0x2F62696C)   = 3 0

 8740/0x15967:      1890       1      0 fstat64(0x3, 0x16BCDDAB0, 0x0)       = 0 0

 8740/0x15967:      1893       4      2 mmap(0x0, 0x4000, 0x1, 0x40001, 0x3, 0x0)        = 0x10457C000 0

 8740/0x15967:      1894       0      0 close(0x3)       = 0 0

As far as I can tell, all the mapping that take place (mmap calls) related to the dylib are done as private. There is only one mapping done as shared, but I can't tell if it's related.
My expected outcome was to see that there is part of the dylib shared between the two process, but that's not what I understand from the above experiments.
Did sharing of the read-only sections occur?

looks like only system libraries are shared https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55336505/do-dynamic-libraries-have-the-same-virtual-memory-address-in-all-programs

What OS are you using? Linux, FreeBSD, AiX, Solaris, VMS, Windows, DOS, Qnx, something else? The answer is likely to differ..

The attached example is from MacOS. However, I performed a very similar experiment in RHEL. Two executables, one depends on a.so and the other on a.so and b.so. I started monitoring the memory (free -m -s 2), then I ran the first executable and I see a jump in buff/cache when a.so is loaded, and I immediately start the second executable, however, I only see a jump in buff/cache when the b.so is loaded. I think this shows that a.so is loaded only once and shared between the two processes.

For most operating systems with a global filesystem page cache, all of the initially loaded physical pages backing the mmap'd library should be shared.  For the read-only segments (read-only data or executable segments), they should continue to be shared for the whole lifetime of the mapping.  For writable sections, the data is probably shared initially but then copied privately when the owning process actually writes to the page (thus making changes that should not be visible to other sharers).  Note that zero-filled regions are generally allocated anonymously and not mapped from a file (the library just says "N bytes of Zeros go here" and doesn't generally contain N bytes of zeros).
I believe most dynamic linkers work roughly like this, given a path to a shared library image that needs to be loaded: read the header to understand the layout of the shared library binary (i.e. the ELF header lists the "sections" and how those should be mapped into the address space).  Then for each section, mmap the file-backed section into the address space (the virtual address may be different for each address space).  Some sections are read-only, some are executable, some are writable.  The zero-backed sections might be an anonymous mmap region.
It's not really the linker's job to make sure this memory is shared among processes.  The OS has the opportunity to share pages between processes because it presumably can see this same file is being mapped into multiple address spaces, and can thus share the physical pages it is using the cache the file content in memory.  It can share read-only pages easily, and read-write pages can initially be shared (via copy-on-write support).
See A way to determine a process's "real" memory usage, i.e. private dirty RSS? for some tips on digging into the virtual address space and getting at some of the differences in ownership of the pages backing an address space (TL;DR sudo vmmap on Mac, maybe cat /proc/<pid>/maps on Linux?).

It depends upon the operating system. Most modern operating systems will allow such sharing. The executable or shared library file can serve as the page file for code and static data. Some operating systems will do that. As multiple processes load the executable or shared library, the operating system simply maintains a reference count.
The compiler/assembler, linker, and loaded all affect whether a library can be shared after loading.
There are certain prerequisites. The shared library must have position-independent code in order for it to be shared. The code must use relative offsets rather than explicit references to memory. With bad coding, it is possible to create a library that cannot be loaded once and shared, even on a system that support it.
Some systems set aside sections for parts of a library with bad things.

static int a
static int *b = &a

That cannot be position independent but it can be put in a separate section that is not shared while the rest of the library is shared.
